# PHP OOP query returns either blank or Array

Tags: php, mysql, oop

New to OOP.

Trying to query the database for a specific row.
Database is structured as:
id - title - value

*(I am trying to query match title and get the subsequent value)*

The query either results in **Array** or is simply blank.

Certain my formatting is mixed up or incorrect somewhere.  Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Query (which inside the same model where this is being called from) **catalog/model/order.php**:

```
public function getTemplate($title) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM km_mail_templates WHERE `title` = '" . $this->db->escape($title) . "'");

    foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
            $template_data[$result['title']] = $result['value'];
    }

    return $template_data;
}
```

Variables I am trying to call:

```
public function index() {//called from within order.php model
  $this->getTemplate()['new_greeting'];
}
```

Also tried:

```
$this->model_catalog_order->getTemplate()['new_greeting'];
```

and

```
$this->model_catalog_order->getTemplate('new_greeting');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the query doesn't find anything, the `foreach()` body will never be executed, so you'll never initialize `$template_data`, and you'll return `null`. You need to initialize it to an array before the loop.

And since you're just overwriting the same array element each time through the loop, there's no point in looping, just get the one element from the array.

There doesn't seem to be any need to return an array, you can just return the value that was retrieved by the query as a string.

```
public function getTemplate($title) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM km_mail_templates WHERE `title` = '" . $this->db->escape($title) . "'");

    if (!empty($query->rows)) {
        return $query->rows['value'];
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
$greeting = $this->getTemplate('new_greeting');
```

Comment: Thank you!  I modified my code to the above, but I still must be calling it incorrectly in index(): `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getTemplate() on null in..` and the line: `$this->model_catalog_order->getTemplate()['new_greeting']` (other variations I've tried are in my original post)

Comment: If the query doesn't return anything, it's not going to put anything into `$template_data`, so what do you expect to get from the `new_greeting` element?

Comment: Also, why aren't you giving an argument to `getTemplate()`? It expect the title to search for as an argument.

Comment: 'new_greeting' is what I am trying to query with $title.  `$this->model_catalog_order->getTemplate('new_greeting')` yields the same error.  In the database, title row, new_greeting column = test. ("test" is what I am trying to echo).. sorry if I've not explained correctly.

Comment: thanks a TON for your help and clear explanations.  I now understand what I was doing wrong & got it working!!